# Showing $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, complex-numbers

> I wish to show that if $z$ is real, then 
>   $$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$$

I have shown this result, although my inequality is the wrong way around.

I considered
\begin{align}
|z^2+1|&\leq |z^2|+|1| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(triangle inequality)} \\
&=|z|^2+1 \\ \\
\Rightarrow |z^2+1|&\leq |z|^2+1 \\
\frac{1}{|z^2+1|}&\geq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1} \\
\frac{|e^{iz}|}{|z^2+1|}&\geq\frac{|e^{iz}|}{|z|^2+1} \\
\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|&\geq\frac{e^{-\text{Im}(z)}}{|z|^2+1} \\
\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|&\geq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(if $z$ is real $\Rightarrow$ Im$(z)=0$)} \\
\end{align}

Where did I go wrong?

> Also, I wonder, would this inequality still hold if $z$ was not real?

Comment: It seems to me that there is an equality. Your consideration is not wrong. For complex $z$ the LHS is unbounded while the RHS is bounded, hence the inequality does not hold.

Comment: I am not sure about the last intermediate step, but the circle $|e^{iz}| $ always is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|=\frac{\left|e^{iz}\right|}{\left|z^2+1\right|}= \frac{1}{\left|z^2+1\right|}$$

and

$$0\le\left|{z^2+1}\right|= |z|^2+1$$

therefore the result follows.

Comment: Was there a fault in my working?

Comment: For z real we have $|z^2+1|= |z^2|+|1|$ but $ |e^{iz}|\le 1$.

Comment: Why doesn't $|e^{iz}|=1$?

Comment: @Bell Opsss...yes of course $|e^{iz}|=1$

Comment: I still am confused on the inequality sign in the result. If both expressions are equal, why is it $'\leq'$?

Comment: @Bell Recall that $3\le 3$ is true as $3\ge 3$. Therefore $$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$$ is true since $$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|=\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$$

Comment: @Bell Indeed by definition $$a\ge b \iff (a=b) \lor (a>b)$$

Comment: Cool, I agree with this is. But as you said, if $3\leq 3$ is true as $3\geq 3$, then doesn't this mean that $$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\geq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$$ as well?

Comment: @Bell Yes of course bot inequalities are true and indeed $$(a\ge b) \land (a\le b) \iff a=b$$

Comment: Okay cool. So the inequality in the result could go both ways (by definition) for real $z$, but we choose $\leq$ to fulfill the requirements of the proof, althought $\geq$ is still perfectly true?

Comment: @Bell Yes exactly!

Comment: You sir are a legend. Thanks for explaining this (pretty basic) point to me :) I completely understand now

Comment: @Bell You are welcome! It's really a plesure can be useful to you and I also learn a lot dealing with your questions here. Bye

Answer (score 1):

For real $z$ we have $|z|^2=z^2$ and $|e^{iz}|$=1, hence

$$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|=\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is real: $|e^{iz}|=1$, $|z^2+1|=z^2+1=|z|^2+1$, so that
$$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|=\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}.$$

If $z=x+iy$ is complex, with $y$ a large negative number, then $|e^{iz}|
=e^{-y}$ is huge, and so
$$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\gg\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}.$$

Comment: So in terms of the actual inequality in the question, is this possible to obtain? Or is it a strict equality?

Comment: The inequality in the question is true for real $z$, since for real $z$ both sides are equal. It fails for complex $z$; the reverse inequality fails too.

Comment: I agree that the $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|=\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$, but I don't understand why $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$ for real $z$.

Comment: @Bell If $a=b$ then $a\le b$.

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed to say that I don't remember this result. Do you know of a link that may explain it in greater depth? I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 0):

$\geq $ and $\leq$ don't contradict each other! When $z$ is real $|z^{2}+1|=|z|^{2}+1$. This proves that the stated inequality is actually an equlity for real $z$. To see that the inequality may not hold  for complex $z$ take $z=e^{-in}$ where $n$ is a large positive integer.